# Create special JSON file with jquery AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, object

i have the following json file format:

```
{       
"Deutsch":"German",
"Englisch":"English",
"Französisch":"French",
"Spanisch":"Spanish",
}
```

Now I want to read this file and print it in textareas on my website with PHP:

```
$file = '../js/json/en.json';
$json = file_get_contents($file);
$obj = array();
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

$output .= "<table style='width:100%'>";
$output .= "<tr>";
$output .= "<th>German</th>";
$output .= "<th>English</th>";
$output .= "<th>Your Language</th>";
foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
    $output .= "<tr><td><textarea class='german' style='width:100%;' readonly>".$key."</textarea></td><td><textarea class='english' style='width:100%' readonly>".$val."</textarea></td><td><textarea class='new_lang' style='width:100%'></textarea></p></td></tr>";
}
$output .= "</table>";
```

which works well so far.

After that I need to read out the content from two textareas above and write it into a new json file with the same format. This is the part where I have problems so far:

```
$("#save_translation").on("click", function() {

        let obj = {};
        $(".new_lang").each(function() {
            var te = $(this).parents("tr").find(".german").val();
            var tt = $(this).val();
            obj = {...obj, [te]:tt};
        });
        //console.log(obj);

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/trans.php",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {myData:obj},
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // php://input
           success: function(data) {  
                console.log("test: ", data);
            }
        });

    });
```

and the trans.php file:

```
$myArray = $_POST['myData'];
$posts = array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    //array_push($posts, $key .":". $value);
    $posts[] = array("$key" => "$value");
}
var_dump( $myArray);

$fp = fopen('js/json/tfr.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($posts));
fclose($fp);
```

Does anyone have tips on how to do it correctly to get the same format as the one above??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the output look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change

```
$posts[] = array("$key" => "$value");
```

to

```
$posts[$key] = $value;
```